# Android - Insert in DB if value is greater than the value in DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Android studio and Firebase to develop an application. I want to store a score in the database if the value is greater than the score in database. How do I check for that?

```
            userData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    userData.child("score").setValue(count);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I have updated the question. This the code where insert the score in the database. I want to write a "if statement", but i don't know how to get the value from the database to compare with the count variable before inserting.

Comment: Okay, now, did you try do get the value from `userData.child("score")` before you set it?

Comment: The `DataSnapshot` class has the `getValue` method, by the way

Comment: No i have not got the value. Oh, can i use                         DataSnapshot data = (DataSnapshot) dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue(); to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `dataSnapshot` to get the value from the reference.

Then, use that reference to update the data as you have, but add the conditional.

```
userData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final String scoreKey = "score";

        Long oldScore = dataSnapshot.child(scoreKey).getValue(Long.class);
        if (oldScore == null || count > oldScore) { 
            userData.child(scoreKey).setValue(count);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```